# NuxtJs site Contentful

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, contentful

I have created a blog using Nuxt JS and added Contentful to the project

Did this by follow a tutorial from [here](https://blog.theodo.com/2020/03/content-driven-static-website/)
and was able to get all sections like title, date and content of the post

But I’m confused now , how do I get single post and also image from assets

Here is my github repo

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/saiteja-konda/Saiteja.dev)

Please help me out

I want to get single post so that I can make navigation to each post individually

Here is the project hosted on netlify [demo](https://saiteja-dev.netlify.app)

Answer (score 0):

When you call Contentful API getEntries you can specify additional data:

```
const ctfData = await client.getEntries({
 content_type: 'contentType',
 locale: localeIso.iso,
 'fields.property': 'value',
})
```